# Inserting Win32 controls into MFC application

Tags: winapi, mfc

I was wondering if there's a way to insert native win32 controls(button, static, etc.) into a MFC application during runtime. I was abled to embed my dll but everytime I create a new control via CreateWindowEx it is being shown as a white box for a split second and removed instantly. Here's how I'm creating the window:

```
HWND newButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL, "BUTTON", "New button", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 100, 100, 150, 200, mainWnd, NULL, 0, 0);
```